# What range function does to a Python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not able to figure out what is happening here. Appending reference to `range` function is kind of creating a recursive list at index `3`.

```
>>> x = range(3)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> x.append(x)
[0, 1, 2, [...]]
>>> x[3][3][3][3][0] = 5
[5, 1, 2, [...]]
```

Whereas, when I try this:

```
 >>> x = range(3)
 [0, 1, 2]
 >>> x.append(range(3))
 [0, 1, 2, [0, 1, 2]]
```

I can easily deduce the reason for the second case but not able to understand what appending reference to `range` function is doing to the list appended.

Comment: Why is this tagged both Python 2 and 3? `range` behaves differently in 2 and 3.

Comment: Lists are passed by reference in python. This means that in the first scenario, you are appending the pointer to x, not the value of x. Because x now contains a pointer to x, it calls itself recursively at that point.

Comment: @JacobH: saying "lists are passed by reference" makes it seem like lists might behave differently from other objects.  All objects are passed the same way (although people argue about what the right phrase to describe that is.)

Comment: @interjay I mistakenly did that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python2, `range`s are `list`s.

`list`s, and most of the things in python are *objects* with *identities*.

```
li = [0,1]
li[1] = li    # [0, [...]]
              # ^----v
id(li)        # 2146307756
id(li[1])     # 2146307756
```

Since you're putting the list inside *itself*, you're creating a *recursive* data structure.

Comment: Please note that this is Python 2-specific. Ranges are entirely different in Python 3, returning a lazily-evaluated `range` object, not a list at all.

Comment: @Karoly thanks for the answer but I am not able to understand why value assignment of 5 is working. Whatever I have learnt is that if I use a[1][0] = 5, then it means assign 5 to 0 index at list of list at index 1.

Comment: if you meant my example: `li[1]` is `li`, so it's simply `li[0]=5`.

Answer (score 0):

First this is strange, and you probably should not use this in practice. The issue is not specific to `range` function and has to do with references. When you call `x.append(x)`, you essentially say that `x[-1] is x`. So when you modify `x[0]`, you also modify `x[-1][0]`, `x[-1][-1][0]` etc.

To see that this is not range specific, you could use `copy.copy`:

```
from copy import copy

x = range(1)
x.append(x)  # here x[1] is reference to x itself (same object)
print(x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1][0])
x[0] = 1
print(x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1][0])  # all values change

# 

x = range(1)
x.append(copy(x))  # x[1] is a copy of x at previous state (new object)
print(x[0], x[1][0])  # cannot call x[1][1][0] -> x[1][1] is an int
x[0] = 1
print(x[0], x[1][0])  # only the first value changes
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
```